# Planes for tetragonal lattice

Tags: lattices

I've edited a code written for cubic lattice to make it for a tertagonal lattice, but the planes are wrong. They should reach the boundary of the shape, so I need a correction for this code:

```
 Manipulate[ 
 Show[
  LatticeData[ Which[Type == "SimpleTetragonal", "SimpleTetragonal"], 
   "Image"],
  
  Table[ ContourPlot3D[  h*x + k*y + l*z - r == 0,
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, {Blue, Opacity[Op]}],
    Mesh -> False, BoundaryStyle -> Black], {r, -(h + k + l), 
    h + k + l - 2, 2}],
  
  Graphics3D[{Thick,
     Red, Arrow[{{-1.01, -1.01, -1.01}, {1.6, -1.01, -1.01}}],
    Blue, Arrow[{{-1.01, -1.01, -1.01}, {-1.01, 1.6, -1.01}}],
    Darker@Green, Arrow[{{-1.01, -1.01, -1.01}, {-1.01, -1.01, 1.6}}]
    }],
  SphericalRegion -> True, ImageSize -> 1.1 {500, 400}
  ],
  {{Type, "SimpleTetragonal", "lattice"}, {"SimpleTetragonal"}},
 Row[{"Miller indices", Spacer[20],
   Control[{{h, 1, Style["h", Italic]}, Range[0, 10, 1]}], Spacer[20],
   Control[{{k, 1, Style["k", Italic]}, Range[0, 10, 1]}], Spacer[20],
   Control[{{l, 1, Style["l", Italic]}, Range[0, 10, 1]}]}],
 {{Op, 0.5, "plane opacity"}, 0, 1}]
```

Original code from : https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CrystallographicPlanesForCubicLattices/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the variable ranges in `ContourPlot3D` to match the ranges from `LatticeData`, which are wider for this lattice than for the one you were using before:

```
PlotRange@
 LatticeData["SimpleTetragonal", "Image"]

(* Out: {{-1.06, 1.06}, {-1.06, 1.06}, {-1.06, 1.56}} *)
```

So change your `ContourPlot3D` call to:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 h*x + k*y + l*z - r == 0, 
 {x, -1.06, 1.06}, 
 {y, -1.06, 1.06}, 
 {z, -1.06, 1.56}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, {Blue, Opacity[Op]}], 
 Mesh -> False, BoundaryStyle -> Black
]
```

Comment: thanks! @MarcoB  actually it didn't work for me (i changed the whole code to make it work lol) but now i know the dimensions. may i ask how to change lattice dimensions? for example i want a Tetragonal with dimensions 11x11x15 in cm.

Comment: @DemaSD not sure what it would mean for the dimensions to be specified in cm. Everything is relative in an image anyway. What would you need it for?

Comment: because i want to compare the atoms (balls at each corner) volume with cell volume (lattice volume), i already know how to change balls volume using this code for example:
inline `LatticeData["SimpleCubic", "Image"] /. Sphere[cents_, r_] -> Ball[cents, 1.255 r]`